# How to make RestTemplet available while writing integration test for repository while working with MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I am trying to write an integration test for my `MongoRepository` using `@DataMongoTest` with `findById()` and check if the document has some value or not, but the issue is with the `RestTemplate` I am using in my project. It is unable to bind a `Bean` to the `restTemplate` field even though I have given it the `MainTest` class. Below are the details.

I can run this application with local configuration and able to receive data from MongoDB. We are using this `restTemplate` bean in another Service class to call some backend service before fetching data from MongoDb.

#### My Main Class

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class User{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(User.class,args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder {
        return builder.build();}
    }
}
```

#### My Mongo Repository

Here my `Document` object is called `Response` and the `Id` is of type `String`

```java
@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends CurdRepository<Response, String> {

}
```

#### My Main Test Class

I have implemented the Bean as the main class, just in case thinking it might take reference from here. But it did not take reference from here

```java
@SpringBootTest
class UserManagementTest {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() { }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) { 
        return builder.build();
    }
```

#### My Repository Test

```java
@DataMongoTest
public class AccountRepositoryMongoIT {

    @Autowired
    AccountRepository repo;

    Response response = new Response();

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp(){
        response.setId("1234");
        response.setSomeValue("abcd")
    }
  
    @Test
    public void test_GetAccountByID() {
        assertEqual(response.getSomeValue(), 
        repo.findById(id).get().getSomeValue());
    }
}
```

But when I run this, it is failing with the following error:

```
UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'restTemplate' defined in com.java.user.User.....
```

Is there a way that it can be run without using the `@SpringBootTest` annotation because we don't want to bring up the whole container? We just want to test this repo light weight.

**Please let me know if I am missing anything here**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the sliced `@DataMongoTest` annotation, Spring Test will scan for your main Spring Boot class (`User` in your example) and will use it for the sliced context initialization.

As you define there the `RestTemplate` bean that requires the `RestTemplateBuilder` (injected via the method parameter), your context startup fails as this builder is not part of the sliced context that you get with `@DataMongoTest`. It is however available when starting the entire context, that's why it works with `@SpringBooTest`.

**Solution**: Move out any bean definition from your main class. In your example you can outsource the `RestTempalte` creation to , e.g. a `RestTemplateConfig` class

```
@Configuration
class RestTemplateConfig {
  
  @Bean
  public RestTemplet restTemplet(RestTemplateBuilder builder){return builder.buil();}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, this worked. I was using different annotations to make the sliced context have the restTemplet. but this one is a simple fix.